# Database query works in MySQL workbench but not when I try to run them from Java

Tags: java, mysql

I am trying to execute a MySQL transaction from Java. This works in my Workbench, but when I execute it from Java it gives me this: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Insert into User(username, `password`) values ('asd', 'asd'); set @userId = LAST' at line 1

This is my query:

```
 public static final String CREATE_USER = "start transaction;" +
        " Insert into User(username, `password`) values (?, ?);" +
        " set @userId = LAST_INSERT_ID();" +
        " Insert into User_Roles values (@userId, ?);" +
        " commit;";
```

An here is the code for executing this query

```
public static boolean createUser(UserEntity user) {
    try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(Constants.URL, Constants.DATABASE_USERNAME, Constants.DATABASE_PASSWORD)) {
        System.out.println("Database connected!");
        PreparedStatement st = connection.prepareStatement(DatabaseQuery.CREATE_USER);
        st.setString(1, user.getUsername());
        st.setString(2, user.getPassword());
        if(user.getRole().equals("User"))
            st.setInt(3, 1);
        else
            st.setInt(3, 2);
        if (st.execute())
            return true;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

I looked at this question [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17992685/sql-statement-works-in-workbench-but-not-in-java), but I don't have space problems.

Comment: You have five statements, not one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SOLVED]

Yes, you were right I had multiple statements on the same query.

The way I solved it was to modify my database URL so it can accept multiple query separated by semicolon, like this:

```
public static String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/javaDb?allowMultiQueries=true";
```